# How to get the id to set a session variable in php

Tags: php

This first part isn't having any issues now.

```
    <?php
  session_start();
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<div id='name' style='margin-top:50px;'><h2>" . $row['name'] . "</h2>";
    echo "<a href='nextPage.php'><img class='pic' src='".$row['imageURL']."' data-id='".$row['id']."' height='100px'/></a></div>";
    echo "<div id='bio' style='border-bottom:1px solid #000;'><p>" . $row['bio'] . "</p></div>";
  }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('click', '.pic', function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'setSession.php',
      data: {myId: id}
    });
  });
</script>
```

---

After I click an image I just get php error messages telling me there is an undefined variable. I currently have 'setSession.php' as a separate page, not sure if it's supposed to be or not.

```
**Next Page**

    <?php
    session_start();
    include("connect.php");

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from table");

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="<?php echo $row['imageURL'];?>" height="200px"/><br/>
        <div class="textSection" style="text-align:center;">
          <h2><?php echo $row['name'];?></h2>
          <p>
            <?php echo $row['bio'];?>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put data attribute `data-id` on img tag and change `ids` into `class` since `ids` should be unique like so :

```
<img class='pic' src='" . $row['imageURL'] . "' data-id='" . $row['id'] . "' height='100px'/></a></div>";
```

And register `click handler` to `img` using its `class` together with `AJAX` request to set `data id` into `session` variable like so :

```
$(document).on('click', '.pic', function() {

   var id = $(this).data('id'); // get id value from data-id attribute
   $.ajax({
     type : 'POST',
     url : 'setSession.php',
     data : {
      myId : id
     },
     success : function(msg) { /* do something here for success request */ }
  });
});
```

Finally. in `setSession.php` page :

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['myId']; // this come from ajax request
  echo "something"; // and this will available on ajax success callback
?>
```

Comment: I tried what you've suggested, no errors until my 'nextPage.php' loads, the information fails to load. Did the 'setSession.php' code need to be seperate or part of my 'nextPage'?

Answer (score 1):

firstly, you should start session in that page like this.

```
session_start();
```

then access the session variable like this.

```
$_SESSION['your_key_here'];// this will return the value stored in session.
```